# setspace and scrhack package warning "unsupported version"

Tags: setspace

I have a "problem" or better question why it's unsupported or if there is actually any problem or not? My code is the following (simplified):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
    Dummy.
\end{document}
```

This leads to the warning message in the log file:

```
Package scrhack Warning: unknown \onehalfspacing definition found!
(scrhack)                Maybe you are using a unsupported setpace version on i
nput line 96.


Package scrhack Warning: unknown \doublespacing definition found!
(scrhack)                Maybe you are using a unsupported setpace version on i
nput line 118.
```

My questions now: 1) Why? 2) Is there actually anything problematic? 3) Should I not use the package setspace anymore? (better alternative?), ...

My versions are up to date (updated every package via miktex today: 15.03.2023), e.g. setspace package is from 2022/12/04 (v6.7b set line spacing) and scrhack from 2022/10/12 (v3.38 KOMA-Script)

Comment: The `scrhack` documentation says "_Because `scrhack` must be continuously modified to accommodate new releases of third-party packages, it can never be considered complete._" The last update of `setspace` came a couple of months after the latest update of `scrhack`, hence the warnings. I fear the only thing to do is to inform the maintainer of the KoMa script bundle.

Comment: If you don't need the `setspace` hack of `scrhack`, just deactivate it (see the manual for more information).

Comment: Ok thanks will try to do it. Do you think I should avoid using setspace or will it most likely be fine to continue using it? :D

Comment: I wrote a bug report here: https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/tickets/46/ so this question here can be closed I guess. Thanks for the help @campa